# Doctrine 2 ManyToOne multipy JoinColumns

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have next entities:

```
/**
* Customer
*
* @ORM\Table(name="customer")
* @ORM\Entity()
*/
class Customer
{
    /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var Account[]|ArrayCollection
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="customer")
    */
    private $accounts;

    /**
    * @var Account
    *
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Account")
    *
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="customer_id"),
    *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="default_account_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    private $defaultAccount;
}


/**
* Account
*
* @ORM\Table(name="account")
*/
class Account
{
    /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;


    /**
    * @var Customer
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="accounts")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    */
    private $customer;
}
```

Idea that customer has multiply accounts, onr of the account should be default for customer. I would like to use foreign key with multiply fields to ensure that default customer account belongs to this customer, but I'm getting next error:

```
Column name `customer_id` referenced for relation from MyBundle\Entity\Customer towards MyBundle\Entity\Account does not exist.
```

Actually there is no "customer_id" field on ORM level, because it is "customer.id" but I dont know how to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that line `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="customer_id"),` is redundant. Try to configure this field as following:

```
/**
* @var Account
*
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Account")
*
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="default_account_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $defaultAccount;
```

By the way, I think it would be better if you just added a boolean column `is_default` into your `Account` entity.

Comment: There are possibility that default account can be from other customer if I use only one foreign key. So it is better to add two-field foreign key to be sure that default account belongs to current customer on the database level.

Comment: So you need the bidirectional one-to-one association in this case.

Comment: In SQL words I need:  

    ALTER TABLE public.customer ADD CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (default_account_id, id) REFERENCES public.account(id, customer_id)

Comment: But your `Account` entity already has a customer-account conjunction, additional one is redundant. And the case when the default account belongs to another customer is impossible. And as I said, it would be better if you had a field `is_default` in the `Account` entity and a method `getDefaultAccount` in the `Customer` entity that filtered `$accounts` and returned the default one.

Comment: In case adding "is_default" field to the Account it will be possible that multiply Accounts from one csutomer can have is_default flag. It can't be controlled on the database level.